# конвертировать в UTF-16LE c++ linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, c++14

надо с генерировать csv файл в UTF-16le, с русскими и латинскими символами.
делается на linux и для linux.

Пробовал натравить либу iconv, ковертирует криво, латинские символы конвертирует по одному, если сначала идут русские символы то конвертирует либо до латинского либо до знака пробела или любого другого знака, при этом ошибки не возвращает, отладчиком в нее залезть не удалось. 
пробовал выставлять local, у меня Ru_ru.utf8, максимум что я с этого смог добиться это конвертирует в иероглифы. 
Пробовал бустом конвертировать, все те же иероглифы. 
тот же результат с std::codecvt.

например как то так пробовал

```
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>

bufferStr = "1234567890тестоваяtestстрокаstring.дляfor:конвертированияco‌​nvert_чегоany;либоth‌​ing\\воto\nчтоwhat,л‌​ибоyouneed"; 
std::wofstream   os;
os.open(fileExport);
os.imbue(std::locale("ru_RU.UTF-8"));
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter; 
std::wstring wstr = converter.from_bytes(bufferStr); 
os<<wstr;
```

[вот что вышло](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wNE9fwLIwz_PI3jZfEvFV2hFFNBYHHkM/view?usp=sharing)

вот эта функция конвертит что угодно во что угодно, кроме как в utf16

```
char * encoding_convert(const char *in_enc,  const char *out_enc,
                        const char *in, size_t in_size, char *buf)
{
    iconv_t cd;
    size_t t;
    cd = iconv_open(out_enc, in_enc);
    if (cd != (iconv_t) (-1)) {
        t = in_size * 2 + 1;
        if(buf == nullptr)
            buf = new char[t];
        char *out = buf;
        memset(buf, 0, t);
        iconv(cd, (char**)&in, &in_size, &out, &t);
        iconv_close(cd);
        return buf;
    } else {
        mylog_error("error: iconv_open");
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

то есть, если строка начинается с русских символов то конвертит до первого не русского или символа пунктуации.

Comment: Мало информации. Какие байты (не символы, а именно байты) на входе, какие байты на выходе, в какой программе вы увидели иероглифы? По той информации, которую вы дали, можно предположить, что вы просто неправильно читаете готовый файл

Comment: ...или неправильно читаешь ввод, или неправильно пользуешься iconv'ом, или неправильно выводишь всё это...

Comment: собираю просто строку std::string utf 8 конвертирую ее в utf 16, шлю данные в файл, открываю файл в Kate.

Comment: Какие байты получаются в файле?

Comment: строка в итоге вот такая 
bufferStr = "1234567890тестоваяtestстрокаstring.дляfor:конвертированияconvert_чегоany;либоthing\\воto\nчтоwhat,либоyouneed";

Comment: вот на выходе вот это на выходе
 ㄀㈀㌀㐀㔀㘀㜀㠀㤀　䈄㔄䄄䈄㸄㈄〄伄琀攀猀琀䄄䈄䀄㸄㨄〄猀琀爀椀渀最⸀㐄㬄伄昀漀爀㨀㨄㸄㴄㈄㔄䀄䈄㠄䀄㸄㈄〄㴄㠄伄挀漀渀瘀攀爀琀开䜄㔄㌄㸄愀渀礀㬀㬄㠄㄄㸄琀栀椀渀最尀㈄㸄琀漀਀䜄䈄㸄眀栀愀琀Ⰰ㬄㠄㄄㸄礀漀甀渀攀攀搀

Comment: Красота! (По сути мне нечего добавить)

Comment: я пробовал уже [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842984/convert-from-char-to-char16-t) и [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153935/how-to-convert-utf-8-stdstring-to-utf-16-stdwstring)

Comment: [MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) в студию...

Comment: для меня сейчас подойдет любой рабочий вариант конвертирования

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> os.imbue(std::locale("ru_RU.UTF-8"));
> os<<wstr;
> ```

В данном случае `wofstream` на выходе конвертирует всё обратно в "ru_RU.UTF-8", как и запрошено.

Чистого, абсолютно надёжного и переносимого способа выводить utf-16 средствами stl, насколько я знаю, нет. Может к С++20a что-нибудь придумают. Лучшее, что можно придумать — это конвертировать строку и выводить побайтово:

```
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

// ...

std::ofstream  os;
os.open("<file>", std::ios::binary);
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>,char16_t> converter; 
std::u16string u16str = converter.from_bytes("<строка utf-8>");

for (char16_t c: u16str) {
    os.put (  c       & 0xFF );
    os.put ( (c >> 8) & 0xFF );
}

os.close();
```

На LE-системе можно вывести и проще, хотя это и грязновато:

```
os.write (reinterpret_cast<char *>(u16str.c_str()), u16str.size()*sizeof(char16_t));
```

Но ИМХО лучше вместо самопальных костылей использовать какую-либо специализированную библиотеку, от которой можно на выходе получить готовую последовательность байт... тот же, `iconv`, если устраивает оставаться в рамках POSIX; за отсутствием примера, что именно с ним не срослось я не знаю.

Comment: короче, основная проблема с иероглифами заключалась в том что надо побитово в файл записывать.
вот такой вариант тоже работает
`    for (char c: res) {
                    os.put (c);
                }`